# Resample to periodIndex and use initial value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to use an initial value for resample periods for use with `first()` and `last()`.
For example, I'd have daily data to start with, I'd resample to monthly:

```
df.resample('M', kind='period')
```

But when I calculate differences over `last()`, the first period value for Equity will be zero:

```
df.Equity.last().diff()
```

Current result (Equity at 2020-1-1 is 1000):

```
            Equity    Result
Date   
2020-1-31   5000      0
2020-2-29   7500      2500
2020-3-31   12500     5000
```

Desired result:

```
            Equity    Result
Date   
2020-1-31   5000      4000
2020-2-29   7500      2500
2020-3-31   12500     5000
```

How could I do this so that the first period value would be `last()` - `first()` and the latter periods would be `last()` - `last()` as both values are available. Is there an alternative route to achieve this, I'm quite certain I shouldn't need to insert a dummy line into the df every time I do this.

**Example DF with different values:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([n*100 for n in range(10)])
idx = pd.period_range('2020-01-28 09:00', periods=10, freq='D')
df.iloc[0] = 100
df = df.set_index(idx)
dfrs = df.resample('M', kind='period').last().diff()
```

I'm expecting the result for 2020-01 in `dfrs` to be 200 (300-100) instead of `np.nan`.

Comment: What's the original dataframe?

Comment: Updated with an example DF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible idea is use `fillna` for replace first value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([n*100 for n in range(10)])
idx = pd.period_range('2020-01-28 09:00', periods=10, freq='D')
df.iloc[0] = 100
df = df.set_index(idx)
dfrs = df.resample('M', kind='period').last()
dfrs = dfrs.diff().fillna(dfrs[0].iat[0] - df[0].iat[0])
print (dfrs)
             0
2020-01  200.0
2020-02  600.0
```

Comment: Thank you, this does solve the problem. I'm also curious of alternative solutions when dealing with incomplete periods and first/last.

Comment: @misantroop - hmmm, do you think in output are some missing values, not only one and is necessary replce only first `NaN`?

Comment: It's only the first in my case. Using fillna and shifting solves all of the issues.